# I have cmake error when trying to build Gazebo from source

Tags: cmake, gazebo-simu

I am trying to compile [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/) from source.
I ran `cmake ..` in a build directory but get the following errors.

Which packages do I need to install? (Ubuntu 18.04)

```
@evadro-PowerEdge-T620:/tmp/gazebo/build$ cmake ../
-- Gazebo version 11.0.0~pre1
-- Found CPack generators: DEB
-- High memory tests: enabled
-- 

====== Finding 3rd Party Packages ======
-- Operating system is Linux
-- Checking for module 'freeimage>=3.9.0'
--   No package 'freeimage' found
--   freeimage.pc not found, trying freeimage_include_dir and freeimage_library_dir flags.
--   Found /usr/include/FreeImage.h
--   Looking for FreeImage.h - found
--   Looking for libfreeimage - found
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:275 (message):
  Policy CMP0072 is not set: FindOpenGL prefers GLVND by default when
  available.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0072" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  FindOpenGL found both a legacy GL library:

    OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so

  and GLVND libraries for OpenGL and GLX:

    OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
    OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so

  OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE has not been set to "GLVND" or "LEGACY", so for
  compatibility with CMake 3.10 and below the legacy GL library will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake:54 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:147 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find OpenAL (missing: OPENAL_LIBRARY OPENAL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- OpenAL not found, audio support will be disabled.
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine CXX configuration
-- HDF5 Found
CMake Warning at cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake:152 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSimbody.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Simbody", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Simbody" with any
  of the following names:

    SimbodyConfig.cmake
    simbody-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Simbody" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Simbody_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Simbody" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:147 (include)


-- Looking for Simbody - not found
-- Simbody not found, for simbody physics engine option, please install libsimbody-dev.
-- Found DART: /usr/include (Required is at least version "6.6") found components:  collision-bullet utils-urdf dart missing components:  collision-ode
-- Looking for DART - found
-- Using system tinyxml.
-- Using system tinyxml2.
-- Looking for libtar.h - not found
-- Looking for libtar.so - not found
-- Missing: libtar
-- Checking for module 'OGRE-RTShaderSystem>=1.7.4'
--   No package 'OGRE-RTShaderSystem' found
-- Checking for module 'OGRE>=1.7.4'
--   No package 'OGRE' found
CMake Warning at cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake:375 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOGRE.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OGRE", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OGRE" with any of
  the following names:

    OGREConfig.cmake
    ogre-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OGRE" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OGRE_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OGRE"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:147 (include)


-- Missing: Ogre3d version >=1.7.4(http://www.orge3d.org)
-- Checking for module 'OGRE-Terrain'
--   No package 'OGRE-Terrain' found
-- Checking for module 'OGRE-Overlay'
--   No package 'OGRE-Overlay' found
Package OGRE was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `OGRE.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'OGRE' found
-- Failed to find OGRE's plugin directory.  The build will succeed, but gazebo will likely fail to run.
-- Checking for modules 'playercore>=3.0;playerc++;playerwkb'
--   No package 'playercore' found
--   No package 'playerc++' found
--   No package 'playerwkb' found
-- Player not found, gazebo plugin for player will not be built.
-- Looking for GTS - found
-- Checking for module 'libusb-1.0'
--   No package 'libusb-1.0' found
-- libusb-1.0 not found. USB peripherals support will be disabled.
-- Checking for module 'OculusVR'
--   No package 'OculusVR' found
-- Oculus Rift support will be disabled.
CMake Error at cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake:601 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findsdformat9.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "sdformat9", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "sdformat9" with
  any of the following names:

    sdformat9Config.cmake
    sdformat9-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "sdformat9" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "sdformat9_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "sdformat9" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:147 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Did you follow any of the [instructions for building from source](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_from_source&cat=install) ?

Comment: Yes, I followed these instructions to install Gazebo from source on Ubuntu and فاث error occurred in Build And Install Gazebo in step 3 'cmake ../'

Comment: First, you must install all dependencies. Follow this: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_dependencies_from_source

Answer (score 0):

When cloning the repo, did you select the correct branch?
The default branch is gazebo11, so if you're looking to install gazebo9, it'll have to look something like this:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo -r gazebo9 /tmp/gazebo
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a `cmake` error while compiling from source, and I followed these steps to resolve it:

1. Installed the required package; in my case, `sdformat9` was missing.
2. Do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`.
3. Executed `sudo apt autoremove`.

The last and crucial step:

4. Navigated to the build directory `cd build` and removed the previously incomplete build `sudo rm -r *` Then, recompiled it using `cmake ../`.